# How to implement one-to-many relationship with join table using sequelize-npm in node.js

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am writing REST APIs in node.js with sequelize as MySQL ORM. I know, how to achieve n:m relationship between 2 tables using sequelize association. This is well defined [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) in official documentation of sequelize.

I want to achieve one-to-many relationship using a join table.

**My approach to achieve it :**

parent.model.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var Parent = sequelize.define('parent', {
                parent_id:{
                    type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    field:'parent_id',
                    primaryKey: true,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    unique:true
                },
                parent_name:{
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,
                    field: 'parent_name'
                },
        },
        {
            classMethods:{
                associate:function(models){
                    Parent.belongsToMany(models.child, {
                        through:'parent_child_mapping',
                        foreignKey:'parent_id'
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    );
    return Parent;
}
```

child.model.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var Child = sequelize.define('child', {
                child_id:{
                    type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    field:'child_id',
                    primaryKey: true,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    unique:true
                },
                child_name:{
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,
                    field: 'child_name'
                },
        },
        {
            classMethods:{
                associate:function(models){
                    Child.belongsTo(models.parent, {
                        through:'parent_child_mapping',
                        foreignKey:'child_id'
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    );
    return Child;
}
```

After syncing a new table structure is as follows :

[image]

**My Problem:**

- Why sequelize is creating foreign key **childChildId** ?
- Will it work perfectly ?

Answer (score 0):

In parent.model.js you should write

```
Parent.hasMany
```

instead of

```
Parent.belongsToMany
```

If you write "belongsToMany" it actually creates n:m relation as described in here  http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/

Edit: Here is the doc for "hasMany" : 
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/has-many/

Comment: I want one to many association using a third table. hasMany is used to set up 1:m association without a join table